# Size of data scraped using ruby mechanize

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, size, mechanize, html

```
agent = Mechanize.new
url = "---------------------------"
page = agent.get(url)
```

Now, I want to know the KB(kilobytes) of data that has been used by my internet service provider to scrape that data.

More specifically, whats the size in KB, of the variable "page"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
page.content.bytesize / 1024.0
```

Comment: if you need header size also: `(page.header.values.join("\n").bytesize + 2) / 1024.0`

Comment: I saved the page in my desktop as "a.html". Right clicked "properties" and checked, its size is 15.1kb. As you suggested, 1.9.3p385 :026 > ((a.header.values.join("\n").bytesize + 2)/1024.0) + (a.content.bytesize/1024.0)
 => 14.982421875... 14.98 or 15.1??? And you are injecting a "\n", wont that take extra space?? Even 1 byte matters, because Im gonna scrape for the whole year... so please tell me the method to measure it absolutely

Answer (score 2):

It's really two separate things. The size of unzipped response body and the amount of bytes that were transferred. You can get the first by inspecting `page.body`, for the second you would need to measure response and request headers as well as account for things like gzip and redirects. Not to mention dns lookups, etc.

Comment: you are right.. thats what i have been trying to do for the past day... but wont there be a simple ruby method to find out, how much KB of data im requesting and receiving through my ISP..This time ruby's mechanize does that...????

Comment: No, it's network adapter level stuff. That's not what mechanize is for.

Comment: Alright then, i will use page.body.bytesize and display a message that says... an approximate KB of html transported by Mechanize... Sometimes too much is boring...